# How to use committedValuesForKeys to save and reconstitute NSManagedObjects?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, cloudkit

**Nota Bene**

> Please advise in comments if more information is required.

### Background

Using only Apple APIs I am interested in persisting data from an `NSManagedObject` or an object graph to file so that I can save it in CloudKit as an asset and share between users via the public database. Several questions on SO tackle the question of persisting `NSManagedObject`s. None are giving answers appropriate to my use-case.

### Theory

I noted the following entry in Apple's documentation. Since this has been available since iOS 3.0, I wondered whether or not others have used it and if the resulting dictionary could be a suitable solution for persisting the data that I want to send over the wire. My thinking is simply that a dictionary can be archived or written to file and uploaded as a `CKAsset`. The downloaded asset could then be unarchived into a dictionary that should also allow one to reconstruct a new `NSManagedObject` for a new Core Data Context.

[image: committedValuesForKeys]

### Debug Code

So, thinking that of course this is possible, I jumped right in and started working with the dictionary. This code was to try to help me understand the nature of the values one could expect in such a dictionary and how one might use those values to recreate a new object.

```
func debugEncodeObject () {
    if let aManagedObject = self.videoStory {
        if let uncodedObject = aManagedObject.committedValuesForKeys(nil) as? NSDictionary {


            for (key, value) in uncodedObject {
                print("key:\(key)\nvalue:\(value)\ndynamictype:\(value.dynamicType)\ndescription:\(value.description)")
            }
//            let tmpPath = NSTemporaryDirectory().NS.stringByAppendingPathComponent("MNG-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)")
//                print(tmpPath)
//                
//                if uncodedObject.writeToURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: tmpPath), atomically: true) {
//                    print(uncodedObject)
//                    MNGCloudManager.sharedInstance.insertSharedStoryRecord(uncodedObject)
//                    
//                }
        }
    }
}
```

### Complications

So looking at the results of my inspection code I can see that there are several non-standard entries in my dictionary. A couple of the more interesting results show some complications that raise the stakes a bit. For example viewing the value of an `NSOrderedSet` stored in the dictionary shows the in-memory(pointer?) representation of the object including a representation of sub-objects. I do also see a separate representation of the sub-objects so I think I should be able to rebuild new objects with the existing data.

```
key:videos

value:Relationship 'videos' on managed object (0x1467b9750) <ths.VideoStory: 0x1467b9750> (entity: VideoStory; id: 0xd000000000380002 <x-coredata://C26A39CE-7016-48EE-9228-9B6B39E94BFB/VideoStory/p14> ; data: {

    assetURL = nil;

    authoredBy = nil;

    collageImage = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000000 00000000 ffe10080 45786966 00004d4d 002a0000 00080005 01120003 00000001 0001>;

    comments = Story;

    externalGUID = nil;

    externalURL = nil;

    lastModified = nil;

    location = nil;

    metadata = nil;

    ratingsArray = nil;

    sharable = 0;

    sharedWith =     (

    );

    summary = "A saga to tell. ";

    tagCount = 0;

    tagsArray = nil;

    timeStamp = "2015-12-24 19:29:46 +0000";

    title = Story;

    tokens =     (

    );

    videos =     (

        "0xd0000000006c0004 <x-coredata://C26A39CE-7016-48EE-9228-9B6B39E94BFB/Video/p27>",

        "0xd0000000004c0004 <x-coredata://C26A39CE-7016-48EE-9228-9B6B39E94BFB/Video/p19>"

    );

}) with objects {(

    <ths.Video: 0x1467ef540> (entity: Video; id: 0xd0000000006c0004 <x-coredata://C26A39CE-7016-48EE-9228-9B6B39E94BFB/Video/p27> ; data: {

    author = nil;

    comment = nil;

    location = nil;

    tagsArray = nil;

    thumbnail = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000048 00480000 ffe1004c 45786966 00004d4d 002a0000 00080002 01120003 00000001 0001>;

    timeStamp = "2016-01-25 17:21:28 +0000";

    videoFile = "0xd0000000006c0006 <x-coredata://C26A39CE-7016-48EE-9228-9B6B39E94BFB/VideoFile/p27>";

    videoStories = "<relationship fault: 0x1479305c0 'videoStories'>";

}),

    <ths.Video: 0x1467f63a0> (entity: Video; id: 0xd0000000004c0004 <x-coredata://C26A39CE-7016-48EE-9228-9B6B39E94BFB/Video/p19> ; data: <fault>)

)}

dynamictype:_NSFaultingMutableOrderedSet

description:Relationship 'videos' on managed object (0x1467b9750) <ths.VideoStory: 0x1467b9750> (entity: VideoStory; id: 0xd000000000380002 <x-coredata://C26A39CE-7016-48EE-9228-9B6B39E94BFB/VideoStory/p14> ; data: {

    assetURL = nil;

    authoredBy = nil;

    collageImage = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000000 00000000 ffe10080 45786966 00004d4d 002a0000 00080005 01120003 00000001 0001>;

    comments = Story;

    externalGUID = nil;

    externalURL = nil;

    lastModified = nil;

    location = nil;

    metadata = nil;

    ratingsArray = nil;

    sharable = 0;

    sharedWith =     (

    );

    summary = "A saga to tell. ";

    tagCount = 0;

    tagsArray = nil;

    timeStamp = "2015-12-24 19:29:46 +0000";

    title = Story;

    tokens =     (

    );

    videos =     (

        "0xd0000000006c0004 <x-coredata://C26A39CE-7016-48EE-9228-9B6B39E94BFB/Video/p27>",

        "0xd0000000004c0004 <x-coredata://C26A39CE-7016-48EE-9228-9B6B39E94BFB/Video/p19>"

    );

}) with objects {(

    <ths.Video: 0x1467ef540> (entity: Video; id: 0xd0000000006c0004 <x-coredata://C26A39CE-7016-48EE-9228-9B6B39E94BFB/Video/p27> ; data: {

    author = nil;

    comment = nil;

    location = nil;

    tagsArray = nil;

    thumbnail = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000048 00480000 ffe1004c 45786966 00004d4d 002a0000 00080002 01120003 00000001 0001>;

    timeStamp = "2016-01-25 17:21:28 +0000";

    videoFile = "0xd0000000006c0006 <x-coredata://C26A39CE-7016-48EE-9228-9B6B39E94BFB/VideoFile/p27>";

    videoStories = "<relationship fault: 0x1479305c0 'videoStories'>";

}),

    <ths.Video: 0x1467f63a0> (entity: Video; id: 0xd0000000004c0004 <x-coredata://C26A39CE-7016-48EE-9228-9B6B39E94BFB/Video/p19> ; data: <fault>)

)}
```

### Questions

Before reinventing the wheel, am I missing something obvious about the nature and intended usage of this dictionary? Like a built-in API that will do what I want (use the dictionary to build and insert a matching new managed object graph into a different context on a different phone)? Also, are the values in this dictionary `NSValue`s? If so, I would probably need to store them as objects in a new dictionary. Apple provided this information to easily spinoff `NSManagedObject`s to an `NSDictionary`. Am I missing a function to do the reverse?

### Other Thoughts

I do understand that `NSManagedObject`s were originally designed to exist only within a context. However the API method has been sitting there since iOS 3.0, so one supposes that it has some useful purpose. I need to create the most conservative memory usage operation possible. Could anyone with experience in this area share concerns with this approach or suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Use KVC.

For attributes of `NSManagedObject`, use:

```
NSArray *keys = [[[object entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [object dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
```

The resulting dictionary will have its values in standard types as defined in your model. To restore values from such dictionary into instantiated `NSManagedObject`:

```
[object setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dictionary];
```

For relationships there is `relationshipsByName`. By calling `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:` you will get dictionary with its values of `NSManagedObject` type for to-one, and, depending of your model, of ordered or unordered collections for to-many relationships, each containing `NSManagedObject`s. You have to iterate those and get its properties likewise.